# Unable to assemble the query correctly

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

3 Tables:

1. **ParentTable: ParentID**  (assume there's a ParentID = 5)
2. **ParentChildrenTable: ParentID, ChildrenID**  (assume there are 3 relation rows of ParentID = 5)
3. **ChildrenTable: ChildrenID, ChildrenName**  (assume there are 3 children of ParentID = 5, for example: A,B,C)

im trying to do something like "get all children of ParentID=5 and print their names"
**using Entity Framework and LinQ**

using pseudo-like this is what i mean:

```
Parent fifthParent = db.ParentTable.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ParentID == 5);

foreach (ParentChildren parentChildren in fifthParent.ParentChildren) // will iterate 3 times
{
    //get each child seperatly according
    foreach(Child child in parentChildren.Children)
    {
        //print A (on 1st iteration)
        //print B (on 2nd iteration)
        //print C (on 3rd iteration)
    }   
}
```

as far as i can see it it should be 2 for-loops, though im heavy-struggling with that in the last 2 hours.
Hope u could please provide code samples because I still can not grasp the principle of these queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will join everything together and filter it to only return children whose parent's ID is 5.

```
var childrenOfFifthParent = 
    from parent in context.ParentTable

    join parentChild in context.ParentChildrenTable on parent.ParentID
        equals parentChild.ParentID

    join child in context.ChildrenTable on parentChild.ChildID
        equals child.ChildID

    where parent.ParentID == 5
    select child;
```

Then you can do something like:

```
foreach (var child in childrenOfFifthParent.ToList())
{
    // print the child
}
```

Comment: Your solution works great, thanks a lot!, I do not know what I would do without this forum.. Another great solution was given right after, though i like the query-oriented one :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `SelectMany` to flatten the inner collection:

```
Parent fifthParent = db.ParentTable.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ParentID == 5);

var children = fifthParent.ParentChildren.SelectMany(c=>c.Children)

foreach (Child parentChildren in children)
{
   //print children.
}
```

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong because I haven't had to use EF like this yet, but I thought EF had trouble using lookup tables to join data together.

Comment: there's a problem with your second row, .SelectMany(c=>c.Children) are you sure about that?

Comment: @Popokoko: I thought you had three tables nested hierarchically. It looks like you have many to many relationship right?

Comment: as far as i can tell, yes.
parent is the first entity, and child is the second entity. the other table named ParentChildren is a relation table.

Answer (score 1):

I would start the other way around:

```
foreach ( var child in db.ChildrenTable
    .Where( c => c.ParentChildren.Any( pc => pc.ParentID == 5 ) ) )
{
    var foo = child.Name // or whatever else
}
```

Comment: could you please continue this code sample and note how can i loop these children and access their names?

Comment: Edited my answer but that should have been obvious

Comment: your solution also works great, very short and clean, would really like to thank you :) !

Comment: I strongly recommend you make yourself friends with Any operator which allows you to write shorter joins.

Answer (score 1):

Your `ParentChildrenTable` class should look something like this

```
public class ParentChildrenTable
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public int ParentId { get; set;}
  public int ChildId {get; set; }

  public virtual ParentTable Parent { get; set; }
  public virtual ChildrenTable Child { get; set; }
}
```

Which means inside your first loop you could just access the `Child` property of the `ParentChildrenTable` object:

```
foreach (ParentChildren parentChildren in fifthParent.ParentChildren) // will iterate 3 times
{
    ChildrenTable child = parentChildren.Child;

    //print A (on 1st iteration)
    //print B (on 2nd iteration)
    //print C (on 3rd iteration)
}
```

#### UPDATE:

To do this with a single LINQ query you can use `SelectMany` and then a `Select` call:

```
var children = db.ParentTable.Where(p => p.ParentID == 5)
                             .SelectMany(p => p.Children)
                             .Select(pc => pc.Child);
```

Or you can do it starting with the children:

```
var children = db.ChildrenTable.Where(c => c.ParentChildren.Any(pc => pc.ParentId == 5));
```

Comment: Thank you but it seemed u completly ignored i'd like to use LinQ and EF technology. (i see my question title was edited and these elements were removed, i'll re-edit my post to save others time)

Comment: I've updated my answer to include linq queries to get just the children.

Comment: Another great working solution, wow, i got 3 different answers in less than 30 minutes, you guys are awesome and i really appreciate that!